# How might I create this simple shape in StreamPlot?

Tags: plotting

I am wanting to produce this shape, with a top at Y=1 and bottom at Y=-1.
[image: Shape]

I have sort of sketched over it, but the stream shown is correct. I would like a vortex at each side at (-1,0) and (1,0) or maybe no vortex.  How might I create the function for this in StreamPlot?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you possibly give the code you used to generate the StreamPlot you have so far? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anne. I generated it in Wolfram Alpha with StreamPlot[{y,x},{x, -1, 1},{y, -1, 1}] and used Paint Shop to edit it (pasting it together).

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamScale->Full
```

as in

```
StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, 
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 StreamScale -> Full]
```

Comment: Thanks, you all are awesome. I'm trying to plot it in Wolfram Alpha as that's all I have at this moment, and I am getting something completely different, full of noise.  Is there a reason why it's not plotting the same?

StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2},   {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]

https://i.imgur.com/Eyr17sY.jpg

Comment: I get exactly the same in *Mathematica* and *WolframAlpha*.

Comment: @rolypolyman Note that [questions about Wolfram Alpha are explicitly off topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).